# Dynamic data update mechanism for Stack Overflow pages

Tags: javascript, ajax, web, polling

Suppose there is a very active question on SO. You stay at the page for awhile, then you may see the button **1 new answer to this question** or similar buttons for comments if someone adds a new answer or comment.

I experimented a little bit on it by browsing a new question with my Chrome developer console open. However, when the above scenario happens, there is nothing listed in the network section. I expected there would be some periodic `GET` requests issued to the server. Obviously I was wrong.

How does SO implement such functionalities?